# Android Studio Logcat Freezes randomly, with no app crash

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to debug an android app, determining the source of bugs which appear randomly, sometimes after hours of runtime.  I have set it up to capture the needed information in the Android Studio logcat, and to detect the bug conditions and stop sending messages to the logcat when they happen, so that the messages just before the crash are still available in the logcat when I come back to it later.

However, every few minutes my logcat is randomly freezing.  I get no further messages, even though the bug hasn't happened and the app is still running correctly.  The only way I have found to restart the logcat without disrupting my app is to create a new logcat tab, which then works (although I have to manually re-enter my filter and search terms each time).  However, I miss all of the logcat messages from when the old tab freezes until the new one is started.  This is really annoying when I am dealing with underlying bugs that often take hours to appear.  Without these freezes, I could just start it running and come back in a few hours to see if it crashed and get useful logs if it did, but instead I now have to keep actively monitoring it to keep restarting the logcat in a new tab whenever it freezes.

I have restarted Android Studio and my computer many times and this keeps happening.  I have searched both StackOverflow and Google in general for this problem, but my search results are filled up with cases where the underlying app crashes and people don't see the needed information in the logcat, clearly a different problem than I am having but searched for with all of the same keywords.